# Unable to Create a new project in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I am signed in to Firebase, but when I try to create a new project I get the message "Action is Forbidden."  What do I have to do to create a project.  My Project Name is Test MSearch1

Comment: I suggest you contact firebase support for this.

Comment: Thank you Andre  I will post the answer here

Answer (score 0):

I could not create a project because my company's policy had changed and limited project creation to only a few individuals.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the issue here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17026